# R keras tfidf asking for tf-idf and tf-idf asking for tfidf

Tags: python, r, keras, tf-idf

I am trying to create a fake news classification model for class and have been trying to do it with Keras.

```
library(keras)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(readr)

#loading data
df <- read_csv("train.csv")
test <- read_csv("test.csv")

df %>% count(label)

#splitting data
training_id <- sample.int(nrow(df), size = nrow(df)*0.8)
training <- df[training_id,]
testing <- df[-training_id,]

num_words <- 10000
max_length <- 50
text_vectorization <- layer_text_vectorization(
  max_tokens = num_words,
  output_mode = "tfidf"
)


#modeling
text_vectorization %>% 
  adapt(df$text)

input <- layer_input(shape = c(1), dtype = "string")

output <- input %>% 
  text_vectorization() %>% 
  layer_embedding(input_dim = num_words + 1, output_dim = 16) %>%
  layer_global_average_pooling_1d() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 16, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dropout(0.5) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")
model <- keras_model(input, output)

model %>% compile(
  optimizer = 'rmsprop',
  loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
  metrics = list('accuracy')
)

history <- model %>% fit(
  training$text,
  as.numeric(training$label == "real"),
  epochs = 30,
  batch_size = 512,
  validation_split = 0.2,
  verbose=2
)

results <- model %>% evaluate(testing$text, as.numeric(testing$label == "real"), verbose = 0)
results

plot(history)
```

the problem occurs specifically on this part

```
num_words <- 10000
max_length <- 50
text_vectorization <- layer_text_vectorization(
  max_tokens = num_words,
  output_mode = "tfidf"
)
```

while it works with output mode "count","int", and "binary" when I run it with tfidf I get this error

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: TextVectorization's output_mode arg received an invalid value tfidf. Allowed values are `None`, or one of the following values: ('int', 'count', 'binary', 'tf-idf').
```

when I run it with tf-idf I get this error

```
Error in match.arg(output_mode) : 
  'arg' should be one of “int”, “binary”, “count”, “tfidf”
```

if anyone know a solution for this I will be very thankfull

Comment: Welcome to SO. Judging by the error message changing `output_mode = 'tfidf'` to `output_mode = "tf-idf"` might do the trick. Between the two error messages, 'tfidf' and 'tf-idf' are both used, and you've already tried 'tfidf'. HTH

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and the brief answear but when change it to output_mode = "tf-idf" i get the second error. I mean when i use tfidf it tells me i should use tf-idf and when i use tf-idf it says i should use tfidf

Comment: what's your `packageVersion('keras')? Seems like a useful, topical project and would be nice to see results. I would say it is cool, though hard.

Comment: As u suggested I updated keras, r, rstudio and tensorflow. i think its a bug in the package im gonna report the devs on the issue

Comment: If you're able to establish it as bug, write up and accept your own answer here as that will complete this Question with Answer process. Look forward to seeing you crack this.

Answer (score 0):

I have established it as a bug and reported to the R keras team in github. luckily since R is an open source I have managed a solution, not perfect since I still can't compare it with cross validation but since the learning process already does that it is unnecessary.

All I had to do is do a trace `trace("layer_text_vectorization", edit=TRUE)`

and place

```
if (output_mode=="tfidf")
      output_mode <- "tf-idf"
```

after

```
output_mode <- match.arg(output_mode)
```